# I can't make a correct insert request using Doctrine Rest Driver to a Symfony API Plataform

Tags: rest, api, symfony, doctrine

I have two aplication made in Symfony.

In one I have an API made using API Plataform:
https://api-platform.com

In the other I'm using **Doctrine Rest Driver** to make request like if I where using a database.

https://packagist.org/packages/circle/doctrine-rest-driver

I can make select operations, but when I try to insert API complais about the MIME Type:

```
The content-type \u0022application/x-www-form-urlencoded\u0022 is not 
 supported. Supported MIME types are \u0022application/json\u0022
```

I tried to make Doctrine API Plataform to work with x-www-form-urlencoded but I can't, makes the API don't work even with select operations:

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/form-data/#accept-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-form-data

¿Is there anything I can configure in Doctrine Rest Driver to send request using json and not `x-www-form-urlencoded?`

### Code block from comment section:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$localidad = new Localidad(); 
$localidad->setNombreEs("PruebaD"); 
$localidad->setNombreEu("FrogaD"); 
$em->persist($localidad); 
$em->flush();
```

Comment: how do you send the data?

Comment: With doctrine instructions $em       = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $localidad = new Localidad();
        $localidad->setNombreEs("PruebaD");
        $localidad->setNombreEu("FrogaD");

        $em->persist($localidad);
        $em->flush();